# What will be number of tokens(compiler)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, token

What will be number of tokens in following ?

int a[2][3];

I think tokens are -> {'int', '[', ']', '[', ']', ';'}

Can someone explain what to consider and what not while compiler calculates tokens ?

Thanks

Comment: How the input is tokenized is a function of your tokenizer (scanner).  In principle, the input you presented might be tokenized as `"int"`, `"a"`, `"[2]"`, `"[3]"`, for example.  In practice, the most likely choice of tokenization would be `"int"`, `"a"`, `"["`, `"2"`, `"]"`, `"["`, `"3"`, `"]"`.  I am uncertain why you seem to think that the variable name and dimension values would not be represented among the tokens -- they carry semantic information and therefore must not be left out.

Comment: yeah, you are correct, we have to consider 'integers' also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:
How the input is tokenized is a function of your tokenizer (scanner).  In principle, the input you presented might be tokenized as `"int"`, `"a"`, `"[2]"`, `"[3]"`, `";"`, for example.  In practice, the most likely choice of tokenization would be `"int"`, `"a"`, `"["`, `"2"`, `"]"`, `"["`, `"3"`, `"]"`, `";"`.  I am uncertain why you seem to think that the variable name and dimension values would not be represented among the tokens -- they carry semantic information and therefore must not be left out.

Although separating compiling into a lexical analysis step and a semantic analysis step is common and widely considered useful, it is not inherently essential to make such a separation at all.  Where it is made, the choice of tokenization is up to the compiler.  One ordinarily chooses tokens so that each represents a semantically significant unit, but there is more than one way to do that.  For instance, my alternative example corresponds to a token sequence that might be characterized as

```
IDENTIFIER, IDENTIFIER, DIMENSION, DIMENSION, TERMINATOR
```

The more likely approach might be characterized as

```
IDENTIFIER, IDENTIFIER, OPEN_BRACKET, INTEGER, CLOSE_BRACKET, OPEN_BRACKET,
        INTEGER, CLOSE_BRACKET, TERMINATOR
```

The questions to consider include

- What units of the source contain meaningful semantic information in their own right?  For instance, it is not useful to make each character a separate token or to split up `int` into two tokens, because such tokens do not represent a complete semantic unit.
- How much responsibility you can or should put on the lexical analyzer (for instance, to understand the context enough to present `DIMENSION` instead of `OPEN_BRACKET, INTEGER, CLOSE_BRACKET`)

**Updated to add**:

The C standard does define the post-preprocessing language in terms of a specific tokenization, which for the statement you gave would be the "most likely" alternative I specified (and that's one reason why it's the most likely).  I have answered the question in a more general sense, however, in part because it is tagged [compiler-construction].

Comment: I have one doubt, wouldn't the compiler(C-compiler) does preprocessing before lexical analysis and 'int a[2][3];' becomes 'int *(*(a+2)+3);' ? Now number of tokens will be 13.

Comment: The C prepocessor first tokenizes, at least conceptually.  Its behavior is defined in terms of "preprocessing tokens", and its output in terms of "tokens".  This is foremost for the purpose of definition, however, not a constraint on implementation.  In any event, what makes you think the preprocessor converts one of those expressions to the other?  They are equivalent, but neither needs to be transformed into the other in source form.